Trying to find an IC for RF Tx Rx switching
I want to built a T/R switch for 75W at 433 MHz. I found ICs to not be able to withstand that power. How does one build such a switch?
I understand that an IC is not the best solution to this, but I will be leaving this link as it is the only IC I could find that can withstand that power so far: https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/skyworks-solutions-inc/SKY12245-492LF/10210282
The switch will have to work only if it is wanted to change between Rx Tx modes, since it will be used in a SSB voice communication transciever it has to be switched on and off minimum 2-3 seconds and can extend to a day if no talking is done and will stay at Rx Mode. I believe 40dB isolation should be possible for a hobby circuit, with 1 dB loss. I would love to hear your suggestion if it is possible, or should have less loss and higher isolation.

Hi! Welcome here. We have a rule that questions asking for product recommendations are off-topic here, and I'm afraid you question happens to be one of these. What you seem to be doing wrong is assuming one can just easily handle 75W in a chip. Assume transporting your signal in and out of the chip has a loss of only 5% (an insertion loss of 0.22 dB, which would be very good). Suddenly, 5% of 75W heat up your IC. That's 3.75 W! That is a huge amount of power for an IC, especially an RF IC.

So maybe I could encourage you to ask the actual question that underlies your request for product recommendations: Is it OK if we changed this question to "I want to built a T/R switch for 75W at 433 MHz. I found ICs to not be able to withstand that power. How does one build such a switch?"

(you will be asked to add more information, by the way: how fast does your switch have to switch between the ports? How often? How well must the unconnected port be isolated from the other ports? What is an acceptable loss?)

(by the way, this is a very impressive IC; thanks for pointing me to it. Not surprised there's only one you could find; the design requirements of getting PIN diode drive well-controlled enough while still having excellent thermal bonding of all lossy components to the environment are quite interesting, I'd say.)

thanks for the edit! You have to realize that for a first prototype, we still need to know whether you will need to switch every 100 µs or once per hour. And generally, isolation is hard to "optimize" when the principle of the circuit doesn't allow for that, so giving us a ballpark would definitely help :)

Mechanical or solid state switch?

@Raonoke I don't have an area limit, I couldn't find many alternatives for solid state switches and a mechanical switch is no problem, if it is the right way to do.

@MarcusMüller Thank you for your helpful comments, I tried to guess the needed requirements. Would love to hear your further suggestions.

@AliTeo great! That really helps a lot. I'm currently travelling, but I'll hopefully find the time to reply.

For narrowband/single band applications a solid state switch with PIN diodes can do the job. Below is an example. The shown PIN diodes are placeholders. For the transmitter path (D5) you will need a proper power PIN diode which will be the most expensive part in the switch.
The power PIN diode will need to dissipate worst case about 0.5...1W during transmission at full output power with constant envelope modes like FM. For cooling purposes replace C4 and C2 with low impedance, open ended transmission lines and put the diode in between.
For enhanced isolation  of the receiver during transmission, I employed two lumped 1/4 lambda transmission lines in series, each shorted by two low power PIN diodes.

The AC sweep analysis shows the return loss seen by the transmitter (S11), the transmission loss to the antenna (S21) and the isolation of the receiver (S31) that could theoretically be achieved at 433MHz.


Good answer. This is also how I would do it, with 1/4 WL line in place of L1 and L2.
